# Fatal error when using email queue laravel

Tags: laravel, email

Basically i'm trying to send email from laravel to the selected emails. I have 2 environment, my local machine, and an ftp server and the error is on the ftp server.

I send email on my laptop and it works just fine, everything goes normal but when I tried it on my ftp server, there's an error that said this:

```
exception: "Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError"
file: "/home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/Uuid.php"
line: 46
message: "During class fetch: Uncaught ErrorException: include(/home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/composer/../ramsey/uuid/src/DeprecatedUuidMethodsTrait.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:578\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(266): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()\n#1 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(578): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}()\n#2 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(578): include('/home/u8885352/...')\n#3 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader::Composer\\Autoload\\{closure}()\n#4 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/Uuid.php(46): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass()\n#5 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(578): include('/home/u8885352/...')\n#6 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader::Composer\\Autoload\\{closure}()\n#7 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php(1238): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass()\n#8 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(141): Illuminate\\Support\\Str::uuid()\n#9 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(127): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createObjectPayload()\n#10 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(105): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createPayloadArray()\n#11 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(92): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createPayload()\n#12 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(57): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->push()\n#13 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php(233): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->pushOn()\n#14 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(419): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable->queue()\n#15 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/PendingMail.php(135): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->queue()\n#16 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/app/Http/Controllers/InboxController.php(124): Illuminate\\Mail\\PendingMail->queue()\n#17 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\InboxController->storeData()\n#18 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()\n#19 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(260): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()\n#20 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()\n#21 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(798): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()\n#22 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()\n#23 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#24 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()\n#25 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#26 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()\n#27 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#28 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()\n#29 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#30 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()\n#31 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#32 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()\n#33 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()\n#34 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#35 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()\n#36 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#37 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()\n#38 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#39 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()\n#40 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()\n#41 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(740): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()\n#42 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(729): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()\n#43 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()\n#44 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()\n#45 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#46 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()\n#47 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()\n#48 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#49 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()\n#50 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()\n#51 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#52 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()\n#53 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#54 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()\n#55 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#56 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()\n#57 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#58 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()\n#59 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()\n#60 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()\n#61 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()\n#62 /home/u8885352/public_html/dev-riderunner/new_ride_runner/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()\n#63 {main}"
trace: []
```

And when I tried to find the problem, i found that the error is caused by using the send emails with queue and the inboxEmail implements **ShouldQueue**.

```
Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new InboxEmail($attributes['title'], $attributes['body'], $user->full_name));
```

but when I send the email without queue and removed **ShouldQueue** in the inboxEmail class and directly sending it, it went just find and the email is sent successfully.

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new InboxEmail($attributes['title'], $attributes['body'], $user->full_name));
```

I tried using the `queue:restart` command and it didn't fix the problem. Also I already check the mail smtp server, InboxMail class, and the config file for mail and all of that is the same with what's on my local machine (keep in mind that on my local machine, this code work fine, and days before also, the send email feature work find on ftp. It just suddenly broke).

Comment: Interesting profile picture …. anyways, fatal error mostly occurs when a class import is missing, the exception error is cut off on that point …

Comment: Thanks for the respond. The exception error has been updated, you can take a look @dbf

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`, if that doesn’t fix it, remove the vendor directory and reinstall all packages with `composer install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dbf for the answer. I implement the solution to my ftp server and it worked. The problem is solved.

I ran the command below for including all the missing imports and files

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).